# Accessing Voice Messages through my iphone application

Tags: iphone

Thanks in advance.
  Is it possible to access my native voice messages through application programmatically in iphone.

Comment: What kind of message? email? text messages? or do you mean the messages objects pass to one another in objective-c?

Comment: Thanks for ur response: Voice messages.

Comment: Do you mean voicemail from the phone application, or voice recordings from the voice memos application?

Comment: voice mail from the phone application

Comment: Sorry, that's not possible. A lot of carriers are still keeping voicemails on their servers, and not using the iPhone's visual voicemail system, so you probably wouldn't even be able to do it on a jailbroken device.

Comment: Thanks Brian Willis: Is it possible to read normal text messages.